# Would a candle in very high gravity blow itself out?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, buoyancy, combustion

A candle creates an upward draft of hot air, without which the flame would be [spherical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQQ1OHW1_F4). The buoyancy generated is proportional to the density difference as well as the strength of gravity.

Suppose a candle was placed on a "planet" with an Earth-like atmosphere at "sea level" but with 1000 times Earths gravity. Such an atmosphere would be only a couple dozen meters thick! If the candle was then lit, would the flame's updraft blow itself out?

Comment: According to this, no, because you aren't moving the entire flame front which is also the reason why an airplane on fire won't blow itself out: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102678/44539

Comment: It also makes sense because if it they could, a turbine engine would blow itself out and a turbine engine is probably quite similar to your envisioned scenario is.

Comment: As far as know, the fuel jets in a turbine engine have deflector cups at the base of the flame to prevent the 'wind' carrying the flame front away from the fuel nozzle. There are small holes in the cup to allow enough slowed down air in for the combustion process.